# Why does it say 'Undefined Index'?

Tags: php, html

Why does it say Notice: Undefined index: Absent?

```
<form>
    Absent<input type="radio" value="Absent" name="Absent" id="Absent"/>
    <input type="submit" value="update" name="update"/>


    <?php
    $name="";
    $leaves=0;
    if(($_POST['Absent']==="Absent") && !empty($_POST['name']))
    {}
</form>
```

Comment: Where's your form?

Comment: while loading your php page, $_POST['Absent'] is undefined. so, it is showing that notice. you can remove this notice by keeping following error reporting error_reporting( error_reporting() & ~E_NOTICE ) or use isset($_POST['Absent']) it will resolve your problem

Comment: use isset($_POST['Absent']) it wont show notice

Comment: check `print_r($_POST)` and check what are the values are coming in array